# php/html interest calculator white page

Tags: php, html

Hey guys i have problems with my interest calculator. It uses php and html. When i click on my calculate button i get an white page what did i worng. Here is my code can you guys me a tip how to solve it.
Edit: Didn't copy the whole Zins3.php iam going to fix the issues in the html.
Edit2: Is the code now correct?
PHP Zins3.php:

```
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btSubmit'])) {

$mKapital = $_POST[tfK];
if($selected_radio == '1'){
$mProzent = '1,5';
$mTage = '90';
$mZinsen = $mTage * $mProzent * $mKapital / 36000;
echo "Die Zinsen betragen $mZinsen";

}
if($selected_radio == '2'){
$mProzent = '1,7';
$mTage = '180';
$mZinsen = $mTage * $mProzent * $mKapital / 36000;
echo "Die Zinsen betragen $mZinsen";
}

if($selected_radio == '3'){
$mProzent = '2,0';
$mTage = '360',
$mZinsen = $mTage * $mProzent * $mKapital / 36000;
echo "Die Zinsen betragen $mZinsen";
}

}
?>
</body>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Kapitalrechner</title>
  <link rel="stxlesheet" href="Format.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<form action="Zins3.php" method="post">
  <h1>Zinsrechnung
Ihrer
Kapitalanlage</h1>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Kapital:</td>
        <td>
        <p> <input name="tfK" size="10" maxlength="20" type="text"></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zinssatz:</td>
        <td>
        <p> <input name="rbP" value= 1 checked="checked" type="radio"></p>
90 Tage mit 1,5% p. a.
        </td>
        <td>
        <p><input name="rbP" value= 2 unchecked="checked" type="radio"></p>
180 Tage mit 1,7% p. a.
        </td>
        <td>
        <p><input name="rbP" value= 3 unchecked="checked" type="radio"></p>
360 Tage mit 2,0% p. a.</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p>
  <input name="btSubmit" value="Ausrechnen" type="submit"><input
 name="btReset" value="Zur&uuml;cksetzen" type="reset"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you miss the opening tags?

Comment: Your code is incomplete, and you didn't specify which file it was. Are you showing `Zins3.php`? If so, there isn't even a starting `<?php` tag at the beginning.

Comment: Your code is simply full of syntax errors (and some other problems). Have you ever coded in PHP?  If not, you should complete some tutorials first.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the last closing braces in the php code?

```
} <<<<< Why is this here? You may need to remove this.
?>
</body>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is only one problem.

Comment: right, all the semicolons are missing. Post has a missing quotes. Spaces in ==

Comment: Yeah and why is he defining numbers as strings. There are issues in the HTML as well.

Comment: ...
$mKapital = $_POST['tfK'];
...
$mProzent = '1.5';
...
$mProzent = '1.7';
...
$mProzent = '2.0';
...

Do post the final code once the above mentioned changes are done.